# How to use sap.m.Shell together with sap.ui.unified.Shell without artifacts

Tags: sapui5

I'm using `sap.m.Shell` to get the side border/frames on desktop devices and `sap.ui.unified.Shell` to get the features it provides.  But when I use these two shells together, my app renders with a gap at the top and the bottom footer toolbar slightly below the visible page area.

Gap at top:

[image: Top of page]

Bottom footer rendering slightly below page. Note how bottom of button is not visible:

[image: Bottom of page]

Using either of these controls in isolation does not produce this problem.

In my `index.html` file I create the the sap.m.Shell as follows:

```
// Create component container for our component and place in content div
new sap.m.Shell({
    app: new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
        component: oComponent
    })
}).placeAt("content");
```

In my main `App.view.xml` I'm creating the Unified Shell as follows:

```
<mvc:View
  controllerName="webapp.controller.App"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns:u="sap.ui.unified"
  xmlns="sap.m">
  <u:Shell
    id="webappShell"
    icon="/art/logos/meteor-ui5.png">
```

```

The [Unified Shell example at OpenUI5](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.ui.unified.Shell/samples) does not display these artifacts however the demo code does not show how the `sap.m.Shell` is instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar occured to me. I got rid of that spaces by setting margin of the body;

```
body{
    margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks very much for your answer.   Would still like to know why that's necessary since both Shells provide different functionality and should be able to be used together without manually fiddling with the CSS but since you've fixed my problem I'll mark it as the accepted answer.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks. You are definitely right about the default behavior. I really don't have a detailed answer for it or don't know what should be done to avoid it, instead of this css trick.

Answer (score 1):

By default the `body` element gets the class `sapUiBody` which results in a margin of 0.

I wonder why your `body` element does not have that class.. but it may have to do with the hierarchy of your elements.

Right now you have

```
body
|___ m.Shell
     |____ unified.Shell
```

But imo the proper way would be

```
body
|___ unified.Shell
     |____ m.Shell
```

---

To achieve this I did the following:

**1. Create a Shell.view.xml**

```
<mvc:View xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:u="sap.ui.unified" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="my.controller.Shell">
    <u:Shell
        id="unifiedShell">
        ....
    </u:Shell>
</mvc:View>
```

(also create a respective controller for your view if necessary)

**2. Put this in the index.html**

```
<script>       
    sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
        // create a new Shell that contains the rootview
        var oShell = new sap.m.Shell({
            app: new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
                name: "my",
                height: "100%"
            }),
            id: "myShell"
        });

        // load the view that contains the unified shell
        var oShellView = sap.ui.view({
            type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML,
            viewName: "my.view.Shell",
        });
        // access the unified shell from the view
        var oUnifiedShell = oShellView.byId("unifiedShell");
        // place the app shell in the unified shell
        oUnifiedShell.addContent(oShell);
        oShellView.placeAt("content");
    });
</script>
```

---

Your `App.view.xml` does not need to contain a unified shell. This is also great if you are planning to launch your app in a Fiori context: The Fiori Launchpad already has a unified shell, so with your approach you would have two unified shells. By loading the unified shell only in the index.html (which gets ignored in a Fiori context, there the Component.js is accessed directly) you will have your custom shell in a non-Fiori context and the default shell in a Fiori context.

Comment: Hi sorry it's taken so long for me to reply, but I've only just had another occasion to wan to do this.  

Thanks for your detailed response but I've just tried it and with the hierarchy the way you describe it, the unified shell header goes the full width of the screen where as the content in the sap.m.Shell has the unpopulated left and right margins on desktop.  I want both the unified shell header and the page content to have the same width and use the same content area.